# Why does my Nlog database target writes entries multiple times to db?

Tags: nlog

We have NLog in use with normal file-based configuration.

In a shared assembly we need to track specific entries in a database, no matter how some consumers configure their logging. So in application startup we configure the database target by code in addition to the existing config, like so:

```
var logger = LogManager.GetLogger("dummy"); // make sure NLog loads config files first

var dbTarget = new DatabaseTarget() {
   ConnectionString = connStr,
   CommandText = cmdInsertText,
}

dbTarget.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo() { Name = "@logged", Layout = "${date}" });
// some other params 

LogManager.Configuration.AddTarget("_db", dbTarget);
LogManager.Configuration.LoggingRules.Add(new LoggingRule("Our.SpecificValues.*", LogLevel.Trace, dbTarget);
LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
```

We made sure that this initialization code is just run once.

Our problem: Every entry we log appears multiple times in the database (sometimes just twice, but I saw an entry being written 6 times to the DB).
The NLog internal log shows that the statement is executed multiple times, but I can't find a reason for that in the log. The other configured (file) targets only write the entry once.

The question. How can I figure out, why the entry is written to the database multiple times or what do I have to do to have it only written once to the db?

Comment: If you can reproduce this (unit test?), please file a bug :)

Comment: I ran into A similar issue today when I was running unit test. Is this what happens to you?